# Content Toggling Issue - 1 At A Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a toggle script for a website I'm building & I'd like to toggle one thing at a time, but it does it all at once. You can see what I mean [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20998737/dadsite/services.html).

Here's the code that goes between the head tags:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").hide(); //added this line
    $("p").click(function(){
        $("ul").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the code that goes in the body:

```
<p class="toggle">+ <span class="intoggle">Apple iPad 2</span></p>
<ul><li>Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $99.99</li>
<li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (Black) – $109.99</li>
<li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (White) – $109.99</li></ul>

<p class="toggle">+ <span class="intoggle">Apple iPad Mini/Mini Retina</span></p>
<ul><li>Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $139.99</li>
<li>Retina Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $139.99</li>
<li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (Black) – $129.99</li></ul>
```

I want to toggle only one `<p></p>` at a time. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of just calling `ul` (which will target all `ul`'s) you want to target the one specifically after the `p` that was clicked. `$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked then you can call `next()`

```
$(this).next("ul").toggle();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryp1v4k2/)

Comment: Your answer is correct except for the line "if you ever added another element in between those two your code would still work".  The code would not work if another element was inserted as the selector passed to `next` would not match the element and nothing would be returned.  http://jsfiddle.net/ryp1v4k2/1/

Comment: yes you're correct, I was actually thinking of `siblings()` when I wrote that for some reason. But even in this case, because they are all siblings using `siblings()` would trigger both `ul`'s. I removed that note.